# Cartoon spider feet -- Any ideas?

Tags: sound-effects, gameaudio, animals, insects, creature

Making sounds for a cutesy iPad game for little kids learning to read. At one point there is a cartoon spider that runs across the top of the screen. The producer has requested a sound for this. I'm kind of at a loss. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Re-watch A Bug's Life for tons of ideas. If you can get the DVD, there's a whole track where it's SFX only: No dialogue, no music. Full of neat ideas there. Seem to remember that Ben Burtt used handcuff ratchets for the feet of the roach in Wall-E. Just some ideas of existing SFX to get you unblocked.

Close-up, dainty, tight foley or SFX seem like they'd work well: Keeping footfalls short, truncated, short, like quiet IDM/electronic clips/hits/thwips. Just another thought.

But, of course, it all depends if it's meant to be funny, creepy, silly, or a notification of some kind.

Answer (score 3):

Take an Unbreakable plastic comb (for your hair), bend the tines back with your thumb, and let them pop up one by one.

Comment: ooh, good idea!

Answer (score 2):

I might try a small (very) garden trow or small hand shovel in grass, time compressed and pitched up. Bugs usually get a "skittery" sound no matter what kind of feet they have. The time compressions will shorten it and make it a tiny tap. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

You could maybe try dropping small pasta shells or tapping your nails on a hard surface. If it's a cutesy kids thing I imagine something like a xylophone run would help soften the mood as the spider runs past as well.

Comment: good call on the xylophone